# Huge stack of credential dialogs when switching user

Tags: 19.04, update-manager, login-screen, 19.10, switch-user

I have reported this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1831332

My question is that what would be the correct package/component for this? I filed that against update-manager, but not sure if that's correct.

Comment: update-manager is wrong, but they'll fix it.

Comment: Well, I doubt that as 6 months has elapsed without a single comment :)